# Creating new pandas df from old one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe data, and want to append another one at the end. The new dataframe  is similar to the previous one, only the entries are swapped. I have the following code that works and illustrates what I am doing:

```
listL = data.shape[0]  
length = data.shape[1]
mid = (length-1) / 2.0
for j in range(0, 5) :
    data.loc[listL+j] = data.iloc[j]

for j in range(0, 5) :
    for i in range(start, end) :
        left = int(ceil(mid+i)) + 1
        right = int(ceil(mid-i))
        data.iloc[listL+j][left] = data.iloc[j][right]
        data.iloc[listL+j][0] = data.iloc[j][0] + 10
```

In this example I am adding only the first 5 rows at the end, and swap the columns. This does not scale well at all, and it is very inefficient. 
Can you help make this more efficient, eliminate the loops, and make it scale well (I would like to work with dataframes that have 10000's of entries).
In particular, how can I make the swapping more efficient?

Update:
Using one of the answers, I can now do:

```
tmpdf = data
data = pandas.concat([data, tmpdf])

for j in range(0, listL-1) :
    for i in range(start, end) :
        left = int(ceil(mid+i)) + 1
        right = int(ceil(mid-i))
        data.iloc[listL+j][left] = data.iloc[listL+j][right]
        data.iloc[listL+j][0] = data.iloc[listL+j][0] + 10
```

where listL is the number of rows in the original df data. I need to optimise the second part:

```
listL = data.shape[0]  
length = data.shape[1]
mid = (length-1) / 2.0 
for j in range(0, listL-1) :
    for i in range(start, end) :
        left = int(ceil(mid+i)) + 1
        right = int(ceil(mid-i))
        data.iloc[listL+j][left] = data.iloc[listL+j][right]
        data.iloc[listL+j][0] = data.iloc[listL+j][0] + 10
```

Comment: Can you post example data frames and a desired output? That will make it easier to help you.

Comment: for the second part just do `data[data.columns[:mid].tolist()+data.columns[(mid+1):].tolist()]`

Comment: @JoeR  The code is all there. Say data = [x, 1, 2, 3], I want to create new df =[[x, 1, 2, 3],[x+10, 3,2,1]], that is I am doubling the rows, the first value is increased by 10, everything else is reflected about the middle column.

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel Not sure I understand this. How is this swapping the data about the middle column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `df1` and `df2`, you can simply use `pd.concat` to add `df2` first five rows, independantly of how columns are ordered:

```
pd.concat([df1, df2.ix[:4,]])
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing, thanks to the answers and comments received:

```
length = data.shape[1]    
mid = (length-1) / 2.0

start = -int(floor(mid))
end = int(floor(mid))

#for j in range(0, 5) :
#    data.loc[listL+j] = data.iloc[j]

tmpdf = data.copy(deep=True)
for i in range(start, end) :
    left = int(ceil(mid+i)) + 1
    right = int(ceil(mid-i))
    tmpdf[data.columns[left]] = data[data.columns[right]]

data = pandas.concat([data, tmpdf])
```